# Integrating BAM and CEP. - No features to be installed

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep, wso2-bam

When I try to integrate CEP into BAM following the documentation I get a message that

> no features will be installed.

Along with the summary.

> Your original install request has been modified. org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.dataaccess.feature.group-4.2.2 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.common.feature.group-4.2.2 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.server.feature.group-4.2.3 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.registry.resource.properties.feature.group-4.2.0 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. org.wso2.carbon.databridge.streamdefn.registry.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.server.feature.group-4.2.2 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.cassandra.mgt.feature.group-4.2.2 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon - Service Management Feature 4.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.feature.group 4.2.1) Software currently installed: Key Store Management Feature 4.2.4 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.feature.group 4.2.4) Only one of the following can be installed at once: WSO2 Carbon - Security Management UI Feature 4.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.jar 4.2.2) WSO2 Carbon - Security Management UI Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.jar 4.2.0) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Key Store Management Feature 4.2.4 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.feature.group 4.2.4) To: org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.group [4.2.2] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Security Management UI Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.group 4.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.jar [4.2.0] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Security Management UI Feature 4.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.group 4.2.2) To: org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.jar [4.2.2] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Service Management Feature 4.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.feature.group 4.2.1) To: org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.feature.group [4.2.0] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Service Management UI Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.ui.feature.group 4.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui.feature.group [4.2.0]

Any ideas how to resolve this and integrate these?

It appears to be an issue with recent releases, old releases integrate fine. Dropping features to be integrated as they cause issues which are highlighted in the summary seems to be one way to work past this but is far from ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From BAM 2.4.0 onwards, the core CEP features have also been included inside BAM by default. There is no need to install CEP features separately. However, the CEP dashboard will not be available since BAM has its own dashboard.

If you use BAM 2.4.0, CEP features released for CEP 3.0.0 will be available. If you need CEP 3.1.0 features in a BAM pack, you can use BAM 2.4.1.

You can verify what is the corresponding version of CEP features for a particular BAM pack by referring to the WSO2 release matrix [1]. The latest BAM pack will always ship with the latest CEP features available.

[1] http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Is there a way i could get access to the CEP dashboard, or elements of the CEP dashboard through BAM 2.4.1.

For example many of the monitoring tools from CEP are not available on BAMs monitor dashboard/tab.

Comment: Setting up the CEP dashboard on top of BAM is not something that has been tried and tested before. If you go for this option, you might have to do some configuration changes as well to get it working properly.